# Python: using np.apply_along_axis with a function returning array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to do something like the following

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([0,1,2,3])
fn = lambda x: np.array([x/2,x*2])
res = np.apply_along_axis(fn,0,arr)
```

That is, I want to use `np.apply_along_axis` with a function that returns an array rather than a single value. However, this results in the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 117, in apply_along_axis
    outarr[tuple(i.tolist())] = res
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,4) into shape (2)
```

While I would expect the outcome to be equivalent to:

```
res = np.array([[0.0,0],[0.5,2],[1.0,4],[1.5,6]])
```

Note that my actual use case is more complicated than the `fn` given. I would like to know whether there is a way in general to use `np.apply_along_axis` with a function that returns an array, or whether there is a different (numpythonic) way to achieve the same thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround I have found is to stack the results, to make your lambda return a 1D array instead of a 2D one:

```
arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
fn = lambda x: np.hstack([x/2, x*2])
res = np.apply_along_axis(fn, 0, arr)
```

and then you can reshape `res` as you want

Comment: I had something like this in mind as a solution too but couldn't figure out how to write it. A nice workaround for sure. What reshape would result in exactly the `res` I require, though?

Comment: I since found two ways to reshape the result to my fit my the example: `res.reshape(4,2,order='F')` and `res.reshape(4,2).T`. Although it seems that just reshaping without specifying `order` or transposing the result is sufficient in my actual use case. I don't quite understand the mechanics yet...

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing--applying a regular Python function along an array--is basically the same as a `for` loop.  It's not going to be very fast, even if you use NumPy functions to invoke your function.  So just keep it simple:

```
arr = np.array([0,1,2,3])
fn = lambda x: [x/2,x*2]
res = np.array(list(map(fn, arr)))
```

Or if you care about performance:

```
arr = np.array([0,1,2,3])
funcs = [lambda x: x/2.0, lambda x: x*2.0]
res = np.empty((len(arr), len(funcs)))
for i, func in enumerate(funcs):
    res[:,i] = func(arr)
```

This second way is much faster, so long as you have more rows in the array than the number of functions to apply.  This is because you only loop a few times, using NumPy vectorized code to apply each function to the entire input at once, rather than looping over the input rows one by one.

Comment: Your first solution results in an object of the form `array(<map object at 0x7f3b4b590710>, dtype=object)`, I'm not sure how to work with that? It seems that it can't be indexed.

Comment: Your second solution works for my simple example but it I don't think it generalises very well, for example when the resulting array is much larger (requiring many more assignments of the form `res[:,i] = ...`).

Comment: In Py3 you have to use `list(map(...))`.  Or try `np.array([fn(i) for i in arr])`.

Comment: @Marein: As hpaulj said, you have to use `list(map())` in Python 3.  I updated my answer to do that.  I have also updated my second solution to be fully general, yet still fast.